# How to update multiple siblings in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm creating a decision matrix app using ReactJS. I'm having trouble figuring out how ReactJS updates multiple components of the same type that are direct children of the same parent.

Problem: Only one component updates while identical siblings do not

Steps to reproduce:

1) Enter characters into the 1st input box

2) Enter characters into the 2nd input box

3) Press the 'Add Task' button

4) The task is now in all 5 of the category divs. It is the same task entered 5 times.

5) Enter a category number (1-4) in one of the identical task's input boxes

6) The number only updates for the task where you entered the input, but not for any of the other identical tasks

Immediate desired effect: Each of the identical tasks will update its category number identically

Greater desired effect: To update the category number of a task so that it only shows up in the box of a matching category number (or, if it has no category number, it is in the 'no label' category box)

Snippets/Functions/Etc to look at: handleListTaskChange, handleTaskChange, handleCategoryChange

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/t9etyjr1/

The categories hold the tasks

```
// -Categories (4)
// (urgent/important, urgent/unimportant, non-urgent/important, non-urgent/unimportant)
const Category = React.createClass({
  handleTaskDelete(taskId){
    this.props.onListTaskDelete(taskId)
  },
  handleTaskChange(taskId, categoryId){
    this.props.onListTaskChange(taskId, categoryId)
  },
  render(){
    let opts = {}
    function predicate(condition, test){
      if (condition){
        return () => test
      }
      return () => true
    }
    const taskNodes = this.props.data
      // .filter((task, index) => {
      //   return predicate(
      //     !this.props.isLast,
      //     parseInt(task.category, 10) === index + 1)()
      // })
      .map((task, index) => {
        return (
          <Task
            author={task.task.author}
            text={task.task.text}
            key={task.task.id}
            taskKey={task.task.id}
            onTaskChange={this.handleTaskChange}
            onTaskDelete={this.handleTaskDelete}
            category={task.category}
          />
        )
      })
    return (
      <div className="category">
        <h2>{this.props.categoryTitle}</h2>
        {taskNodes}
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

The Matrix Box holds everything

```
// -MatrixBox
const MatrixBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      taskData: [],
      categoryData: [
        {name: 'urgent/important (1)'},
        {name: 'non-urgent/important (2)'},
        {name: 'urgent/unimportant (3)'},
        {name: 'non-urgent/unimportant (4)'},
        {name: 'no label'}
      ]}
  },
  handleListTaskDelete(taskId){
    const tasks = this.state.taskData
    const newTasks = tasks.filter(task => (task.task.id !== taskId))
    this.setState({taskData: newTasks})
  },
  handleListTaskChange(taskId, categoryId){
    const tasks = this.state.taskData
    const newTasks = tasks.map(task => {
      if (task.task.id !== taskId) return task
      task.task.category = categoryId
      return task
    })
    this.setState({taskData: newTasks})
  },
  handleTaskSubmit(task){
    const tasks = this.state.taskData
    task.id = Date.now()
    const newTasks = tasks.concat([{task, category: ''}])
    this.setState({taskData: newTasks})
  },
  render(){
    console.log(this.state.taskData)
    const categoryNodes = this.state.categoryData.map((category, index, arr)=>{
      return (
        <Category
          categoryTitle={category.name}
          key={index}
          categoryKey={index}
          onListTaskDelete={this.handleListTaskDelete}
          onListTaskChange={this.handleListTaskChange}
          isLast={(index + 1 >= arr.length)}
          data={this.state.taskData}
        />
      )
    })
    return (
      <div className="matrixBox">
        {categoryNodes}
        <TaskForm onTaskSubmit={this.handleTaskSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

The tasks go into the category boxes

```
// -Tasks
const Task = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {category: ''}
  },
  handleDeletePress(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onTaskDelete(this.props.taskKey)
  },
  handleCategoryChange(e){
    this.setState({category: e.target.value})
    this.props.onTaskChange(this.props.taskKey, e.target.value)
  },
  render(){
    let category = this.state.category
    if(category !== ''
        && parseInt(category, 10) < 5
        && parseInt(category, 10) > 0
      ) {
        console.log('New value is ' + this.state.category)
      }
    return (
      <div className="task">
      {this.props.author}&nbsp;
      {this.props.text}&nbsp;
      <form onSubmit={this.handleDeletePress}>
        <button>Delete</button>&nbsp;
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Category #"
          value={this.state.category}
          onChange={this.handleCategoryChange}
          maxLength="1"
        />
      </form>
      &nbsp;
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Use the Task Form to create tasks

```
// -TaskForm
const TaskForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {author: '', text: ''}
  },
  handleAuthorChange(e){
    this.setState({author: e.target.value})
  },
  handleTextChange(e){
    this.setState({text: e.target.value})
  },
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let
      author = this.state.author.trim(),
      text = this.state.text.trim()
    if(!author || !text) return
    this.props.onTaskSubmit({author, text})
    this.setState({author: '', text: ''})
  },
  render(){
    return (
      <form className="taskForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Who are you?"
          value={this.state.author}
          onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Whaddaya got to say?"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={this.handleTextChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
      </form>
    )
  }
})

// ReactDOM render the stuff
ReactDOM.render(
  <MatrixBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
)
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do..?

Comment: Once I create a task with a form, I want to enter a number to assign it to a category.

Process: Create task, assign it to category, it shows up in that category's div/Category component. Does that make sense?